# Deleting first occurrence from many to many collection entry at rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In many to many fields `delete` method is deleting all the occurrence of collection. Say I have:

```
class user < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :cars
end

class car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

users and cars are many to many relationship, I have defined my `users_cars` table. Now user can have repetitive car entry as relation. For example:

Car: A,B,C
User: U1,U2,U3

U1=[A,B,C,A,A,A,B]

Which can be implemented using many to many relationship, the way I have implemented. BUT, at the time when I want to delete one of the car entries of user the problem occurs.

```
User.cars.delete(car) #deletes all occurrence of car
User.cars.delete_at(User.cars.find_index(video_card)) #delete_at does not exist
```

Now how to resolve this?

Comment: Can't you just use `User.cars.delete_at(User.cars.find_index(car))` without `User.cars.delete(car)`?

Comment: You mentioned that `User.cars.delete(car)` deletes all the occurrences. Does `User.cars.delete_at(User.cars.find_index(card))` also deletes all the occurrences?

Comment: How are you doing `User.cars`? `cars` method on class level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can't call `User.cars` unless you have defined a class level method `cars` in your `User` model, but in this way, you would return all cars, and that - in no way - would make sense.

Second, `delete_at` is a method that works on `Array` objects, and expects an integer to be passed in. So as a little hack, you can turn your `ActiveRecord::Associations` object into an array, and then call `delete_at` method.

```
user = User.first
user.cars.to_a.delete_at(Car.last.id) # assuming that the last car belongs
# to the first user, something you would never do in actual
# production code.
```

**Edit:**

You can also try the following to achieve the same functionality:

```
user = User.first
user.cars.where("cars.id = ?", Car.first.id).first.delete
```

**Edit 2:**

For what you asked in comment, you can have a model for the table `cars_users`.

```
rails g model CarUser

class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars_users
  has_many :users, through: car_users
end 

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cars_users
  has_many :cars, through: car_users
end

class CarUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And now, you can do:

```
CarUser.where("car_id = ? AND user_id = ?", Car.first.id, User.first.id).first.delete
```

Comment: `to_a` returns new array, so when I would try to save it will be the same, how can I do that? In that case I need to empty the array and refill it, is it the way?

Comment: Sounds great, but I am astonished to see that it did NOT work! It also deleted both of the entries.

Comment: It will always delete only one car. I guarantee it. Try again.

Comment: Even if it came with two results, `first` at the end assures that only result will go forward for deletion, and that would be first result.

Comment: `user.cars.where("cars.id = ?", Car.first.id).first.delete` deletes the entry where I want to delete the entry of their association.

Comment: @sadaf2605 You want to delete the entry in `cars_users` table?

Comment: yep, one entry (except the dup)  :)